# How to order by concatenated values in Entity Framework / Linq?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a situation where the records in a parent table (Record) can have one of two related records in child tables (PhysicalPerson and Company). One of the columns will be always empty.

When displaying the records in a UI grid, user should see only one of the two names in OwnerName column and user should be able to sort the column OwnerName without any knowledge if the OwnerName for any record comes from Company or from PhysicalPerson.

To avoid denormalizing data and copying and maintaining Name column, I attempted to do it all in a Linq query.

Basically, the desired SQL `order by` expression that works should look like this:

```
ORDER BY CONCAT(Record.PhysicalPerson.Name,
Record.PhysicalPerson.Surname,
Record.Company.Name)
```

This would automatically ignore NULL values and results look acceptable.

So I tried to implement it in Linq:

```
query = query.OrderBy(x => x.PhysicalPerson.Name + 
                                        x.PhysicalPerson.Surname +
                                        x.Company.Name);
```

but the resulting query generated by Entity Framework looks like this:

```
[Extent4].[Name] + [Extent6].[Surname] + [Extent8].[Name] AS [C1]
...
ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] ASC
...
```

Obviously, + does not work as a substitute for CONCAT in SQL.

Is there any way to make EntityFramework generate CONCAT instead of + for string concatenation in OrderBy?

If not, then I guess I'll have to create a separate SQL view with calculated column for this specific UI grid (which might be more correct solution anyway).

Comment: I generally go for the principle of letting the database engine to the grunt work and let your C# do as little as necessary to get the desired result. I might be biased from an SQL DBA background but the thought "right tool for the right job" comes to mind.

Comment: You can use `String.Concat(x.PhysicalPerson.Name ?? "", x.PhysicalPerson.Surname ?? "", x.Company.Name ?? "")`.

Comment: @NetMage Thanks, now it generates a query like this:  `CASE WHEN ([Extent4].[Name] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent6].[Name] END + CASE WHEN ([Extent8].[Surname] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent10].[Surname] END + CASE WHEN ([Extent12].[Name] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent14].[Name] END AS [C1]` and it works correctly. I guess, the NULL check was the crucial thing here to get the same result as with `CONCAT`. Feel free to add your comment to a new answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the LINQ translators for SQL/EF don't use `CONCAT` to translate string concatenation, which is inconsistent with the way other translations expect SQL to handle null automatically (or maybe the SQL definition of `+` as different from `CONCAT` is where the issue lies). In any case, you can make the null test explicit like so:

```
query = query.OrderBy(x => String.Concat(x.PhysicalPerson.Name ?? "", x.PhysicalPerson.Surname ?? "", x.Company.Name ?? ""));
```

You could also use `+` instead of `String.Concat`, but I think the intent is easier to see with `String.Concat`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
query = query.OrderBy(x => x.PhysicalPerson.Name).ThenBy(x.PhysicalPerson.Surname).ThenBy(x.Company.Name);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this way all the records with NULL Company are shifted to the very end.

Comment: What when you replace "x.Company.Name" by "x.Company.Name == null ? string.Empty : x.Company.Name"?